# Shouldn't $dU=TdS-PdV$ be true for every closed system?

Tags: thermodynamics, chemical-potential

For a closed system, if there aren't chemical reactions or a phase change inside it, $dU=TdS-PdV$ is the fundamental thermodynamic relation.
This expression can be generalized, for a closed system undergoing phase transition, or chemical reactions, as $dU=TdS-PdV+\sum_i \mu_idN_i$

The generalized relation above seems to have a straightforward physical meaning, it takes into account the energy change due to chemical reactions or phase transitions.

However, when i think that the system is closed, it seems wrong, because, for a closed system, $dU=\delta Q +\delta W $, and, for a reversible process, we have $(\delta Q)_{rev}=TdS$,  $(\delta W)_{rev}=-PdV$. So, substituting, we get $dU=TdS-PdV$, that, since it is an equation between state functions, is true for every transformation.

I pondered about the derivation above, i'm pretty sure that, the equations $dU=\delta Q +\delta W $, and  $(\delta Q)_{rev}=TdS$, are always true for a closed system. On the other hand, i'm not sure about $(\delta W)_{rev}=-PdV$, that may be wrong if the system is undergoing phase transition or chemical reactions. If that is the case, however, i can't figure out why.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not sufficient that the system is closed (i.e., does not exchange matter with the outside world) - it should be also in equilibrium, as all the equations you use are for systems in equilibrium. This includes the *reversible process*, since, by definition, it is a process so slow that at every point the system can be regarded as being in equilibrium.

Further, in statistical physics a change of internal energy is usually decomposed into a change caused by *macroscopic factors* - like changing the volume, change of external field, etc., and *microscopic factors* - e.g., due to the energy exchange between the molecules with the adjacent regions. These are called respectively *work* and *heat*. Work is not necessarily a result of changing volume - we often define generalized forces and generalized coordinates, so that
$$
dU = TdS -PdV+\sum_i F_idX_i
$$
One frequently used example is magnetization and the external magnetic field for magnetic systems (e.g., in Ising model.)

When including term $\sum_i\mu_idN_i$ the notion of *closed system* becomes somewhat ambiguous and loses its value, since this can be viewed as several systems exchanging particles - and hence manifestly *open systems* (rather than closed.)

Comment: even if in this case a closed system can be seen as many open system, it should be regarded as closed system, if taken as a whole. So the formalism work right?

Comment: @SimoBartz well, yes - it is just energy conservation, isn't it?

Comment: if that is the case, $dU=\delta Q + \delta W$ there aren't other energies fluxes (like the energy associated to a mass flow), so, since $(\delta Q)_{rev}=TdS$, we should have $(\delta W)_{rev}=-PdV+\sum_i \mu_i dN_i$. However, i don't see how this work can be seen as force*displacement

Comment: also, the generalized work is $(\delta W)_{rev}= \sum_i X_i dx_i$, where, $dx_i$ are small displacements of the external parameters. Here the only external parameter is $V$

Comment: There are three terms: *work*, *heat*, and *particle exchange*. You are bunching work and particle exchange into work, but then trying to sue the formula for work that is true for system without particle exchange. Essentially, you play on the ambiguity of term *closed system*, noted in the last paragraph of my answer.